# How can dynamically create permission in django?

Tags: python, django

Now I can create new groups using Django group module.
`from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`
I can assign permissions to group. For example I created a new group
"HR"

by `Group(name="HR")` .

Now I want to create permissions like

- can_create_hr
- can_edit_hr

I should able to assign this permission to other groups.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create and assign permission directly to groups as well. Just create the permission add the permission to group

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='model_name')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_create_hr',
                                       name='Can create HR',
                                       content_type=content_type) # creating permissions
group = Group.objects.get(name='HR')
group.permissions.add(permission)
```

If you want to assign this permission to another group then just get the permission object and assign in the same way.

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_create_hr')
group= Group.objects.get(name='some_name')
group.permissions.add(permission)
```

You can read more about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#id1)

Answer (score 4):

If you create a blank migration, you can do something like this (borrowing from above answer):

```
def create_groups_and_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model('auth', 'Group')
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
    Permission = apps.get_model('auth', 'Permission')
    emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, 'default')  # this creates default permissions (in case this migration was run simultaneously with the creation of relevant models and you need to grab those perms)
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='model_name')
    permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_create_hr',
                                   name='Can create HR',
                                   content_type=content_type) # creating permissions
    group = Group.objects.filter(name='HR')
    group.permissions.add(permission)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('lsoa', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_groups_and_permissions)
    ]
```