# Create custom permission dynamically for specific field name of a model in Django

Tags: django, permissions, nameerror

I have created a model and I want to create some groups and permissions dynamically with a specific field name of the model and the group name or permission code name.

For example, if I have **Institute** model with some fields (for example **eiin**, **name**, **address**, **category**), I want a dynamic custom permission called **name_can_edit_address** for the **name** field. Which is working fine (like-**_can_edit_address**) with Meta class but I can't add field name of the model as suffix of the permission(like **name_can_edit_address**) as code name.

It is possible to do that? It's get NameError: name 'self' is not defined.

```
# model specifications

class Institute(models.Model):
    CATEGORY=(
        ('play', 'play'),
        ('High school', 'High school'),
        ('College', 'College'),
 
    )
    eiin = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null= True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY) 



# dynamic group creation ok 

# create group dynamically with the model objects
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Institute, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_students")
        Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_teachers")
        Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_controller")
        Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_employees")
        Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_guardians")


# problem is here. It's not taking name field as suffix of code name for permissions

# create permissions dynamically with institution name & permission code like (field_permissioncode)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            (str(self.name)+'_can_edit_address',
             'can edit address of institute'),
            (str(self.name)+'_can_add_eiin',
             'can add eiin of institute')
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Django permissions are objects*, then they have a dedicated class : `Permission`.
But in Django, permission are linked to `ContentType`.
If you want to create some permission on the fly, you need to create the contenttype and after the permission like this :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Institute, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    Group.objects.create(name=str(self.name)+"_students")
    # ...
    # Create contenttype and permissions, replace app_label and model to fit your needs
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='app_name', model='Institute')
    permission = Permission.objects.create(codename=str(self.name)+'_can_edit_address',
                                   name='can edit address of institute',
                                   content_type=content_type)
    permission = Permission.objects.create(codename=str(self.name)+'_can_add_eiin',
                                   name='can edit eiin of institute',
                                   content_type=content_type)
```

You can find more explanations on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831933/how-can-dynamically-create-permission-in-django)